# KdTree library in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython, kdtree

I need to use [KdTree](https://github.com/codeandcats/KdTree) in IronPython. I built it from source and added library using AddReference. There are plenty of examples of using this library in C# but I cannot translate it to IronPython. I had a problem with creating an object:

C#:

```
var tree = new KdTree<float, string>(2, new FloatMath());
```

IronPython:

```
from KdTree import *
from KdTree.Math import *
tree = KdTree[float, str](2, FloatMath())
```

But I got:

```
TypeError: expected ITypeMath[float], got FloatMath
```

I had checked the source and found the constructor:

```
public KdTree(int dimensions, ITypeMath<TKey> typeMath)
```

And FloatMath is extending TypeMath which implements ITypeMath:

```
public class FloatMath : TypeMath<float>
public abstract class TypeMath<T> : ITypeMath<T>
```

It looks like I cannot pass an argument to constructor because interface is expected. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe you need to create a variable first which holds the float math object?

Comment: @weismat: I tried. Same error. I even tried to create FloatMath using  clr.GetClrType(FloatMath) but It changed nothing.

Comment: Well, I have just made a wrapper in C# which returns KdTree<float, TValue>(dimensions, new FloatMath()). This is not a perfect solution but it works.

Comment: I have a feeling that IronPython is not treating python `float` and .net `System.Float` as equivalent types.  Since `FloatMath` was defined directly as deriving from `TypeMath<float>`, IronPython doesn't have it's hooks there to get any needed metadata. Would the same happen if you came up with a new (python) type that derived `TypeMath[float]` and used that?